# splash-screen not working on ipad device

Tags: ipad, splash-screen

in my apps splash-screen not run on device.but on simulator its work i give name default.png.then only on simulator it works .
also application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:method i add ing on window ,then  work only for simulator. i adjust size by 768*1024.for device .but still not working..anybody has idea abt this let me know
thanks

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];      
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_CARD.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:img]; 
    [self DownLoadProfileInfo]; 
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add File to Resources Folder and Chang it's name as "default.png"..
You r trying an imageView as a splash screen..

Comment: found the solution just have to write sleep(sec)in did finish launching - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    splash_img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    splash_img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splash_img];
    
    sleep(9);
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 1):

Simulator accepts this file name with any case, it could be anything like Default.png, default.png, Default.PNG and DEFAULT.png.

But in device it should be in only one form i.e., Default.png with the 'D' caps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 4.0 or above you need not name them as default. You can just drag and drop them in xcode app settings itself.